# Ionic v3 web app: click event sometimes not triggering

Tags: angular, events, ionic3

I am using ionic3 to develop mobile web app. After a new page loaded, click event doesn't work sometimes. But when I refresh the page, it almost always works again.

I use the following command to build the app:

```
ionic build --prod --platform browser


<ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="index" id="Menubar">
  <ion-tab  [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="tab1" tabUrlPath="rep" tabIcon="tab-replen" *ngIf="repAuth" (ionSelect)="onSelect($event)"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="tab2" tabUrlPath="man" tabIcon="tab-manage" *ngIf="manAuth" (ionSelect)="onSelect($event)"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="tab3" tabUrlPath="per" tabIcon="tab-personal" *ngIf="perAuth" (ionSelect)="onSelect($event)"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

In the component, there is a test method:

```
onSelect(e) {
  alert('selected');
}
```

Comment: You should provide your code so we can examine what could be wrong.
But it could be that something goes wrong in your application and due to error the (click) stops working

Comment: Hey Chu can you share more context how you test your app? ionic serve and in the browser or on a device? which events do not work for you consistently? mouse or touch?

Comment: I have pasted some code. I tested in browser of IPhone of version 8.4 (Sorry I know it is too old) . The app load tab2 first. When I touched tab1, onSelect method triggered. But when I went back to tab2 or touched tab1 again, that method didn't triggered any longer.

Comment: I caught the error: Attempted to assign to readonly property.